# I want to get checkbox values

Tags: javascript

It always says `if (checks[i].checked === true )` this is error I face...

I want to get value from checkbox Value...

```js
function submitFun() {
  var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks')
  var str = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    if (checks[i].checked === true) {
      str += checks[i].value + "";
    }
  }
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="뜨거워"> hot
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="추워"> clod
  <a href="#" onclick="submitFun();return false;">ok </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're iterating three ( 3 ) times when you have two ( 2 ) checkboxes, by the end of your loop, `i` will be `2` and `check[2]` is `undefined`, do `i < checks.length` instead of `i < 3` :

```js
function submitFun() {
  var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks')
  var str = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    if (checks[i].checked === true) {
      str += checks[i].value + " ";
    }
  }
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="hot"> hot
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="cold"> clod
  <a href="#" onclick="submitFun();return false;">ok </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you beat me by time :)

Comment: @SpringerFyou're hero !

Answer (score 0):

Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for selecting all check box also , also use  checks.length in for loop to prevent null pointer on the array

See below working snippet

```js
function submitFun() {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.checks')
  var str = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {

    if (checks[i].checked === true) {
      str += checks[i].value + "";
    }
  }
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="뜨거워"> hot
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="추워"> clod
  <a href="#" onclick="submitFun();return false;">ok </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Avoid attaching events in HTML (it is discouraged)
2. Use array.length while iterating, or better use `Array.forEach()`

```js
function submitFun() {


    var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks')
    var str = "";
    

    for (let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++ ){

        if (checks[i].checked === true ) {
             str += checks[i].value + "";
         }
     }
     alert(str);
}

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', () => {
 submitFun();
});
```

```html
<div class = "container">

    <input type="checkbox" class ="checks" value ="뜨거워"> hot
    <input type="checkbox" class ="checks" value ="추워"> clod
    <a href="#">ok </a>

</div>
```